# How to change the shape of kendo grid 'th'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I want to create kendo grid' another 'th'.
I tried to prepend 'th'. but I don't like the 'th' shape.
I've also tried colspan the 'th' but it didn't work for changing the shape.
How can I change the 'Debit' and 'Credit' th?

**this is my code in kendogrid.**

```
$("#divBillSumBalanceGrid").find("thead").first().prepend("<tr><th class='k-header' style='text-align:center;' colspan='2'>Debit</th><th class='k-header' ></th><th class='k-header' style='text-align:center;' colspan='2'>Credit</th></tr>");
$('th').remove('.k-group-cell.k-header');
```

**this is my current kendogrid 'th'**

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.groupHeaderTemplate or http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerTemplate

Comment: @Lazy Coder, I want to add new 'th' not groupHeaderTemplate. as you can see a picture I posted, I'd like to append Debit, Credit 'th' on Balance, Total, Subject, Total and Balance 'th'

Comment: Well no I can't actually see the pic since my corps firewall blocks imgur, sorry.

Comment: it is not clear what you want. why not just add columns for credit and debit?